# How effective is the quality filter against this question with all-caps brief title and text?

Tags: feature-request, bug, quality-filter, homework-dump

The question [DETERMINISTIC FINITE STATE MACHINE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254595/deterministic-finite-state-machine) (10k link) had the content of:

> DESIGNING A SIMPLE DETERMINISTIC FINITE STATE MACHINE TO RECOGNISE A VALID DUT PASSWORD NUMBER. IT ,MUST FIRST INCLUDE LOWERCASE LETTER,NUMBER AND SUBSEQUENT SYMBOLS @!%$&

What was the quality score for this? How did it get through the quality filter?  And does someone need to change the settings on the threshold for the quality filter for P.SE? or add more rules to the quality filter (e.g. '80% non symbol characters in the character set `[A-Z]` should get automatically rejected)?

This is tagged as both bug and feature request - its either bug that it got through or a feature request to improve it if this was working as designed.

Comment: [73](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5857/31260)

Comment: quality filter is probably case insensitive

Comment: @ratchetfreak I would consider that a bug if that is the case.

Comment: probably worth noting that quality wise letter case matters - I for one perceive all caps much more frustrating compared to all lowercase

Comment: Related reading: [Capslock on VS capslock off](http://theoatmeal.com/pl/minor_differences/capslock)

Comment: And yet DBAs are still allowed to live, @gnat. There's no justice in this world, I tells ya.

Comment: @Shog9 one has to excuse those who can only count "0, 1, many" at times. That said, it would help if the quality filter could be mad aware of such loud postings.

Comment: I think we've got an [accepted answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-effective-is-the-quality-filter-against-this-question-with-all-caps-brief-ti/6854#comment19783_6854 "see update in comments, also edited into the answer")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the ALL CAPS question filter broken?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7479/is-the-all-caps-question-filter-broken)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quality score on that post is 75 out of a possible 100. The threshold for sending it straight into review is 70. Yeah, that's pretty useless.

We're working on a better one, based on some analysis of the available data. It ain't perfect either, but it would've flagged that one right out of the gate.

The new system isn't quite ready to go live yet though, so for now, I threw this in:

> [image: DON'T SHOUT]

---

**[Update](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/how-effective-is-the-quality-filter-against-this-question-with-all-caps-brief-ti/6854#comment19783_6854)**: check is back on - for titles *and* bodies of the questions.

Comment: just... [Add a “Magic 8-Ball” feature to the Ask a Question page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/165773) :)

Comment: this check seems to be done only on the text of the question but not on the title ([SIMPLE DS PROJECT](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/254997/31260 "text apparently lowercased after a warning")), would it make sense to extend it to question title as well?

Comment: Shog, [WHY CAN YOU TURN ON THAT FRIGGIN' MAGIC ONLY FOR QUESTION BODY? ALL-CAPS TITLES ARE JUST AS FRIGGIN' ANNOYING, ESPECIALLY IF YOU TAKE INTO ACCOUNT HOW THESE POLLUTE SITE FRONT PAGE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/257908/31260 "yet another recent example where asker apparently took care of dropping caps in body but left 'em shouting at us in the title")

Comment: Magic is now off - I need a fix before it'll work properly. Will enable for titles as well once I have that.

Comment: @gnat because that would be a new feature request.

Comment: @Shog9 do you need a [magic switch](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html)? I know where to get some at a local hardware store...

Comment: Ok, back on - for titles *and* bodies, @gnat.

Comment: Are you *sure* that its enabled and working properly? http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZmDp.png

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=WHERE%20YOU%20CAN%20USE%20%27%25%22%20IN%20TURBO%20C%2B%2B%20COMPILER @MichaelT - that guy was warned 15 times (about that and other issues)... Didn't stop him from banging his head against the wall though.

Comment: Just making sure... (and oh, thats a neat trick for linking directly to asking a new question).  I'm a bit surprised it made it past the quality filters though with an all caps body.

Comment: Yeah, well... It took him a few tries to get past the filter too. A good few.

Comment: Thats... disappointing (not the filter, though it would have been nice if it caught this too - but rather the "all of these things are saying 'don't post questions formatted like this'").

Comment: Which position is the magic switch in? I'm just wondering if its still working and blocking sufficiently [low quality posts](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286239/about-syntax-importance-in-computer-programming-language).

Comment: Shog, people here complain that [FRIGGIN' ALL CAPS FILTER IS BROKEN YET AGAIN](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7479/31260), we started getting questions with all caps in title and text