# Is the ALL CAPS question filter broken?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, quality-filter

We recently had a [very poor quality question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/288861/53019) seemingly bypass the [filter for all caps in a title](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6854/53019).  And about a month ago, there was [another poor quality question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/285515/53019) that made it through the quality filter.

1. *Bug report:* Can we have someone please check and see if the quality filter is still enabled to prevent those all caps questions?
2. *Feature request:* Can a regression test be generated so that the next time the filter breaks it's detected earlier in the development cycle?

Comment: ALL CAPS FILTER IN QUESTION TEXT IS ALSO BROKEN - [SEE THIS 10K LINK FILLED WITH BLATANT GARBAGE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/288844/31260) - quite annoying

Comment: WHAT ABOUT ALL CAPS COMMENTS?

Comment: @Snowman WE NEED TO FLAG THESE FOR MOD ATTENTION (WITH FLAG MESSAGE IN ALL CAPS)

Comment: FWIW I just tested - "don't shout" warnings were shown when I typed title or text in all caps. Can't figure what's going on. Maybe users ignored it, or maybe they were using mobile version (which lacks filter? if yes that would be funny), or maybe something else

Comment: [LOUD NOISES](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UplJBQi_0_w)

Comment: @gnat A CLIENT SIDE POST TITLE BAN? SERIOUSLY?

Comment: @durron597 just test it yourself. Don't know if it's indeed ban, never tested up to clicking submit - but the warning was there and it looked [exactly as Shog described here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6854/31260)

Comment: given Programmers topics, it looks safe to assume that [block](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7483/31260 "which was just established") won't impact any legitimate question (at Stack Overflow, they probably feed all-caps stuff straight into Triage but [it's not an option over here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7257/31260))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't break. It was a warning, not a block.

Since I'm tired of clarifying this, it is now a block. Expect to observe this circumvented in titles of the form, "THE NeXT PALINDROME".

Comment: Thank you for making the change, and my apologies for missing the earlier statements that it was just a warning.  I think there's a strong correlation between the all caps crowd and the "see textbox, must. mash. keyboard." crowd the pumps out low quality questions.  Switching the warning to a block will at least slow that crowd down a bit.

Comment: @1999 my experience with [problem-title questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7221/31260) over here suggests that some (hopefully many) of blocked askers won't edit but instead, will try their luck at SO which doesn't have this block (and doesn't need it because SO swallows these questions in Triage)